# Understanding the grammar of "non ipsi nos" in Psalm 99

Tags: vulgata

> (Psalm 99:3)  Scitóte quóniam Dóminus ipse est Deus: * ipse fecit nos, et **non ipsi nos**.
>
> (Douay Rheims) Know ye that the Lord he is God: * he made us, and not we ourselves.

How exactly does one parse "non ipsi nos" in this sentence? I would have treated *ipsi* as a nominative plural and *nos* as a direct object and translated the senctence as "Know that the Lord is God; he made us, and they didn't make us." However, judging from the Douay Rheims translation, it looks like something reflexive might be going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to parse *non ipsi nos* is to parse *nos* as a nominative plural pronoun and *ipsi* as a nominative plural adjective. The phrase then means "not we ourselves".

Comment: Though this is possible, the parallelism ("ipse...nos, non ipsi...nos") strongly inclines me to read *nos* as accusative.

Comment: I think you were right the first time. If nos were accusative, there wouldn't really be anything to link ipsi to a first-person subject idea. In that case, I, for one, would naturally read it as 'they themselves' (as indeed the original poster tried to do) – especially since both preceding occurrences of ipse were for a 3rd person singular subject. Plus, the repetition of accusative nos would be pretty clunky. However, I freely confess that I'm completely out of my element in the Vulgate.

Comment: @cnread I think you're right now. The Greek is in the nominative, and usually the Vulgate adheres very closely to the LXX: "γνῶτε ὅτι Κύριος, αὐτός ἐστιν ὁ Θεὸς ἡμῶν, αὐτὸς ἐποίησεν ἡμᾶς καὶ οὐχ **ἡμεῖς**."

Comment: Ok, I removed the alternate parsing from my answer. Thanks guys!